# How can I maximize my critical chance?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'd really like to build a mixed elemental/critical bow ranger (with a huge critical multiplier and, therefore, a high critical chance): it sounds like a nice way to deal great damages.  There are several passive to increase the critical multiplier, but I can't find so many to increase the critical chance, which is pretty low with the bows I've found so far (the basic critical chance is 5%).

I've also read several threads about this build on [their forum](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-forum/24/), but most of them are either outdated, either heavily debated.

How can I increase my critical chance ?  Gear ?  Gems ?  Any passives I have missed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Critical chance can not be less than 5% nor more than 95%.

The base chance for bows is **5%**.

### Passives

There is a full list of general critical strike passives [on the wiki](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Critical_Strike#Critical_Strike_Passives).

- 3 x Increased Critical Strike Chance (20%)
- 15 x Increased Critical Strike Chance (15%)
- 1 x Assassination (30% Increased Critical Strike Chance, 35% Increased Critical Strike Multiplier)
- 2 x Bloodthirst (45% Increased Critical Strike Chance)
- 1 x Mental Acuity (30% Increased Critical Strike Chance, 20 Intelligence)

This gives a combined total of **+400%**

There is [another list](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Bows#Bow_Passives) of Bow specific passives giving a further **+120%**

### Items

Out of the different mods, the "of Incision" [suffix](https://www.pathofexile.com/item-data/suffixmod) gives the most at +38%. This can't appear on all items. however if it could then it would give **304%** (only counting 8 times because of the gloves below).

The [unique gloves](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Unique_Gloves) Maligaro's Virtuosity can be used with a bow and gives **+50%**

### Gems

There is the support gem [Increased Critical Strikes](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Increased_Critical_Strikes) which gives about **+105%** at level 20.

### Skills

Some skills give a critical strike chance bonus. For example [Elemental Hit](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Elemental_Hit) gives a +4% for every [quality](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Quality)%. (so +80% at max quality)

### Curse

There is the curse [Critical Weakness](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Critical_Weakness) which gives **+10%**. However this is treated differently and added after everything else.

### Final Calculation

Total Possible Crit Chance with a bow is 5% * (100% + 400% + 120% + (8*38%) + 50% + 105% + 80%) + 10% = **~73%**

Or an increase of just short of 1,500%. Not that this is practical, but it covers the different ways to boost crit chance.

edit: Assassination has 30cc 35cd, my current version: 1.2 (I didn't check values of other Nodes)

Comment: Critical strike passives link is now http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Critical_Strike#Critical_Strike_Passives